# Android database application not responding

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am making an application to Store textfield values to database.After entering values when I press the button to submit it, it just hanged and give no response.

my onCreate code is given below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

      //---add 2 titles---
        db.open();
        final long d_id ;  
        final EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.isbn);
        final String   isbn   = input1.getText().toString();

        final EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        final String   tText   = input2.getText().toString();

        final EditText input3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.publisherText);
        final String   pText   = input3.getText().toString();

        this.btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        this.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.insertTitle(isbn, tText, pText);

            }
        });

         db.close();
    }
```

}

isbn,titleText and publisherText are my id for Textfield.
insertTitle is function to insert the values.

Whats wrong with my code?

thanks.

Comment: put the `db.open` and `db.close` inside the onClick itself (before and after the insertTitle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the values of your text fields as the app is being created, not when the button is pushed. You will always enter the initial values of your EditTexts with your current code. Try this:

```
db.insertTitle(input1.getText().toString(), input2.getText().toString(), input3.getText().toString());
```

You will have to move where you close your database, otherwise you will get an error for attempting to access a closed database. Try putting it in onPause() or onDestroy().

If this isn't the solution please **post your logcat errors** so we don't have to guess what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    this.btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    this.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
final EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.isbn);
    final String   isbn   = input1.getText().toString();

    final EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    final String   tText   = input2.getText().toString();

    final EditText input3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.publisherText);
    final String   pText   = input3.getText().toString();

            db.insertTitle(isbn, tText, pText);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is `open()`  and `close()` they are in `onclick method` or about your `insertTitle()` method. Check your values and types.

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_WORK_OUT, workout);
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_REP,rep);
    cv.put(KEY_WEIGHT, weight);

    ourDataBase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
```